# Combinations with limited repeats in Python

Tags: python, limit, combinations, python-itertools

I know how to get ALL combinations of a list in Python with itertools, but what if I want to limit the amount of repeats?

So, if I have [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

But I want to limit combinations to only 3 repeats of each item (with a fixed length of the final list, say 10):

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4]
[4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: Can the repeating elements be random or some specific pattern is expected?

Comment: They can be random, I just don't want to end up with something like:

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 ]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 ]

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
import random

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L3 = L * 3
random.shuffle(L3)
L3[:10]
```

Comment: Is there any way to ensure I get all possible results?

Comment: That’s a beautifully elegant way to select a combination randomly from the set of all combinations … but I think the OP wants the set, not a sample from it.

Comment: @TomZych I think you are right. The initial questions was not really clear here but the comments indicate this. Maybe my suggestion is helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way:  Use [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5] and use itertools.combination(*the list from above*, 10).  That would mean that each element occurs at most three times in a resulting list.

Example with smaller list:

Edited to ensure every combination occurs exactly once, the combinations occur in random order and, finally, every combination has a random order.
Also incorporated the idea of Mike Müller to just multiply the list by 3.

```
import itertools
import random
combinations = set()
for c in itertools.combinations(sorted([1, 2, 3] * 3), 5):
    combinations.add(c)
shuffledCombinations = list(combinations)
random.shuffle(shuffledCombinations)
for combination in shuffledCombinations:
    copiedCombination = list(combination)
    random.shuffle(copiedCombination)
    print copiedCombination
```

which will give:

```
[2, 1, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to give me what I wanted (not randomized enough). Maybe I want permutations instead?

Comment: The itertools will provide you with the results in a non-randomized order.  What you could do: Collect the lists in a set (getting all combinations, but no duplicates), and then shuffle them to obtain them in random order.  Or what do you mean by the combination of "I want them all" and "I need randomization"?

Comment: I'm basically trying to find combinations of [0-9][a-f] in 32 spaces but I'm not interested in aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa and so on. Calculating all combinations takes a lifetime and then more, so I thought I could be a bit more intelligent about it and limit it to 3 occurrences of each item.

Comment: Probably an example (for a smaller input set) of what you expect could be helpful - as you mentioned above, possibly you really are looking for permutations rather than combinations, or you want combinations, but not in sorted order, or ...

Comment: I just tried [0-9a-f] in 7 places, and it already gives 157488 combinations (for my algorithm above).  For 32 places, it will still take a lifetime :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to prove a security vulnerability (so it will get fixed, not so I can exploit it) but I think I'm better off doing the math instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more elegant way but that seems to work:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # can contain letters as well
all_combinations = combinations_with_replacement(a, 10)

filtered_results = []
for current in all_combinations:
   throw_away = False
   for item in current:
      if current.count(item) > 3:
        throw_away = True
        break
   if not throw_away:
     filtered_results.append( current )

for j in filtered_results:
   print(j)
```

Comment: What if I want to do letters as well?

Comment: Works just as well without any change. Just try a = ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]