# Un-ordered Combinations with limited replacements

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have to make a list of un-ordered combinations with limited repeats
i.e for a given list of unique elements say card_set create all combinations of length combo_len, with an element repeating at max repeat_limit times

the below code is for combo_len = 3 and repeat_limit = 2 with card_set = range(5)

note i need unordered combinations. 
ie (0,0,1) and (0,1,0) are the same so the solution link below does not satify my conditions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832998/combinations-with-limited-repeats-in-python) post tells me how to get oredered combinations with limited repeats

```
import itertools
import pprint
card_set = list(range(5))
a = sorted(set(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(card_set,3)))
neg = [(i,i,i) for i in card_set]
b = set(a) - set(neg)
print('a###')
pprint.pprint(a)
print('b###')
pprint.pprint(b)
```

the above code gives me a which is unordered combinations with limited 2 repeats ie. neg contains unwanted repeats (0,0,0) (1,1,1) etc 
so 
    `b = set(a) - set(neg)`
give me the required set

for combo_len = 3 and repeat_limit = 2 the above code works. How do i make a code for range(13) combo_len = 7 and repeat_limit = 4

Output:

```
a###
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (0, 0, 4),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 3, 3),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (0, 4, 4),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 4, 4),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 4, 4),
 (3, 3, 3),
 (3, 3, 4),
 (3, 4, 4),
 (4, 4, 4)]
```

---

```
b###
{(0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (0, 0, 4),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 3, 3),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (0, 4, 4),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 4, 4),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 4, 4),
 (3, 3, 4),
 (3, 4, 4)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` class from the `collections` module to find the numbers of repeats of each value in a given tuple. For each tuple, make a `Counter` of it and check the maximum value of the repeats. If that max value is small enough, accept the tuple; otherwise, reject it.

Here is a routine to do this. If I had more time I would pretty this up.

Be careful with this routine. For your given values of `range_size=13, combo_len=7, repeat_limit=4`, the result is a list of length 49,205.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def unordered_combinations_with_limited_replacements(
        range_size, combo_len, repeat_limit):
    return [t for t in combinations_with_replacement(range(range_size), combo_len)
            if max(Counter(t).values()) <= repeat_limit]

print(unordered_combinations_with_limited_replacements(5, 3, 2))
print(len(unordered_combinations_with_limited_replacements(13, 7, 4)))
```

Here is the printout:

```
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (0, 3, 4), (0, 4, 4), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 4), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 4), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 4)]
49205
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, the `neg` used in your example code would only work if the repeat_limit equals the combo_length.

So I searched for something that can count the different elements in a list and came up with `Counter` in the `collections` module. Next step is to iterate over all the elements created by the `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` with a simple `for` loop. If the most common element in the `Counter` object is higher than your repeat_limit, delete that element from the list.

This code will work for every range, combo_length and repeat_limit:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

def getUnorderedCombo(list_range, combo_len, repeat_lim):
    card_set = list(range(list_range))
    a = list(set(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(card_set,combo_len)))
    i = 0
    while i < len(a):
        c = Counter(a[i])
        if c.most_common(1)[0][1] > repeat_lim:
            del a[i]
            i -= 1
        i += 1
    return set(a)
```